# My Observable is not adhering to the define model In Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Good morning guys, I am new to Angular and Observables, I am trying to have my code return an observabe and filter the list but my typescript compiler is given me an error.
this is what i have done so far.

> Movie Model

```
export interface IMovie {
  title: string,
  id: number,
  actors: [],
  url: string,
  producer: string,
  releaseDate: Date
}
```

> movie-service.ts

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
   import { IMovie } from './movies-model';

    @Injectable()
    export class MovieService {
    Movies1: IMovie[] = [
      {
        title: 'Tripple Frontier',
        id: 1,
        actors:[],
        url: 'assets/images/netflix-names/220px-Triple_Frontier.jpg',
        producer: '',
        releaseDate: new Date('24/6/2017')
      },
      {
        title: 'In the name of the father',
        id: 2,
        actors:[],
        url: 'assets/images/netflix-names/In_the_name_of_the_father.jpg',
        producer: '',
        releaseDate: new Date('15/8/2018')
      },
      {
        title: 'When we first met',
        id: 3,
        actors:[],
        url: 'assets/images/when_we_first_met.jpg',
        producer: 'Point blank',
        releaseDate: new Date('15/8/2018')
      },
      {
        title: '',
        id: 4,
        actors:[],
        url: 'assets/images/point-blank-netflix.jpg',
        producer: 'assets/images/point-blank-netflix.jpg',
        releaseDate: new Date('15/8/2018')
      }
    ]

    Movies2: IMovie[] = [
      {
        title: '',
        id: 5,
        actors:[],
        url: 'assets/images/ant-man-and-the-wasp.jpg',
        producer: '',
        releaseDate: new Date('15/8/2018')
      },
      {
        title: '',
        id: 6,
        actors:[],
        url: 'assets/images/netflix-names/vanished.jpg',
        producer: '',
        releaseDate: new Date('15/8/2018')
      },
      {
        title: '',
        id: 7,
        actors:[],
        url: 'assets/images/netflix-names/white_draggon.jpg',
        producer: '',
        releaseDate: new Date('15/8/2018')
      },
      {
        title: '',
        id: 8,
        actors:[],
        url: 'assets/images/netflix-names/220px-Shaft_(2019)_film_poster.png',
        producer: '',
        releaseDate: new Date('15/8/2018')
      }
    ]
    }

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { IMovie } from '../../welcome/welcome-page/movies-model';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators'
    import { MovieService } from '../../welcome/welcome-page/movie-service';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FavMusicService {
      favMovies: IMovie[] = [];
      constructor(private allMovies: MovieService) { }



      addFavMovie(id:number): IMovie[] {
        this.favMovies = this.allMovies.Movies1.filter(x=> x.id == id)
        return this.favMovies.filter(x => x.id == id)
      }
    }
```

The problem is that when i try to addFavMovie, the compiler complain that property id does not exist in IMovie[]. but the property is right there.
please what am I doing wrong.

I don't really know what to do with this line, Maybe Observables is not been corectly inplemented

```
    //This produces error
 addFavMovie(id: number): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return of(this.allMovies.Movies2).pipe(
      filter(x => x.id == id)
  }

 //This code produces no Error
addFavMovie(id:number): IMovie[] {
    this.favMovies = this.allMovies.Movies1.filter(x=> x.id == id)
    return this.favMovies.filter(x => x.id == id)
  }
```

Comment: You didn't show where you are using addFavMovie, please provide the component where you are using it.

Comment: I havent't used it yet, but my typescript compiler is giving an error while declaring the method

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure where you were trying to go with this code ... but I copied it to Stackblitz to better see what was going on.

You can find it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filteringarrays-deborahk

First, as the code stands now, there is no need to use an Observable. Were you getting ready to move from a hard-coded array to an http request?

As others have said, there were a few issues with the code. The FavMovieService could be as simple as this:

```
export class FavMovieService {
  favMovies: IMovie[] = [];

  constructor(private allMovies: MovieService) {}

  addFavMovie(id: number): IMovie[] {
    return this.allMovies.Movies1.filter(x => x.id === id);
  }
}
```

Assuming you don't really need the Observables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, didn't really need the Observable for that, but just wanted to get my feet wet with the concept since I am having hard time wrapping my head around this rxjs observable and Angular in general. Thanks though @DeborahK.

Comment: You could try this: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update  I have a code for a free month if you don't have a subscription.

Comment: Reach out to me PM on twitter and I'll get it to you. @DeborahKurata

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors on your method, first id is not defined, where does it came ? And your method wasn't close, some brackets was missing.

```
addFavMovie(title: string): Observable<IMovie[]> {
        return of(this.allMovies.Movies2).pipe(
            filter(x => x.id === id));
}
```

Id should exist on 'x.id == **id**'. Probably you wanted to use `title` instead. So your function should be :

```
addFavMovie(title: string): Observable<IMovie[]> {
            return of(this.allMovies.Movies2).pipe(
                filter(x => x.id === title));
}
```

Title is the parameter of your method. But, I think you should query your movies by something like that   `filter(x => x.title === title)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 addFavMovie(title: string): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return of(this.allMovies.Movies2).pipe(
      filter(x => x.id == id) //id will give you an error. You are not declaring anywhere, seems like you meant to use id instead of title.
    ); //You forgot to close the .pipe()
 }
```

I think you meant to this:

```
 addFavMovie(id:number): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return of(this.allMovies.Movies2).pipe(
      filter(x => x.id == id)
    );
 }
```